# How to handle asynchronous send and receive in TCP listener

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

I'm new in socket programming. I'm trying to make a TCP listener which can handle multiple connections.

I found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/) example which seems pretty usefull.

The problem with this code is that it sends data to the connected clients only when data received. I want to send data to the connected clients asynchonously.

I see that the `select()` function blocks the code forever until an event arrives at the socket.

I was thinking to put a delay (instead of a `NULL`) in `select()` function so that it timeouts every some microseconds and the program would be able to send data if there's some. At the line `if (buffer[0] > 0)`

The question is: Is there any better way to do what I want? Can I force `select()` to timeout with other way?

The `char buffer[1025];` is a global array that is filled from another thread. The `while(TRUE)` below is running on the other thread.

```
while(TRUE)   
    {   
        //clear the socket set  
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);   

    //add master socket to set  
    FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);   
    max_sd = master_socket;   

    //add child sockets to set  
    for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)   
    {   
        //socket descriptor  
        sd = client_socket[i];   

        //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list  
        if(sd > 0)   
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);   

        //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function  
        if(sd > max_sd)   
            max_sd = sd;   
    }   

    //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL ,  
    //so wait indefinitely  
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_usec = 10000;
    activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , &timeout);   

    if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))   
    {   
        cout << "select error" << endl;
    }   

    //If something happened on the master socket ,  
    //then its an incoming connection  
    if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds))   
    {   
        if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket,  
                (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)   
        {   
            perror("accept");   
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   
        }   

        //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands  
        printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d  \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));   

        //send new connection greeting message  
        if( send(new_socket, message, strlen(message), 0) != strlen(message) )   
        {   
            perror("send");   
        }   

        puts("Welcome message sent successfully");   

        //add new socket to array of sockets  
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)   
        {   
            //if position is empty  
            if( client_socket[i] == 0 )   
            {   
                client_socket[i] = new_socket;   
                printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);   

                break;   
            }   
        }   
    }   

    if (buffer[0] > 0)
    {
        sd = client_socket[0];    
        send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );        
    }  

    //else its some IO operation on some other socket 
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)   
    {   
        sd = client_socket[i];  


        if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds))   
        {   
            //Check if it was for closing , and also read the  
            //incoming message  
            if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 1024)) == 0)   
            {   
                //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print  
                getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , \ 
                    (socklen_t*)&addrlen);   
                printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" ,  
                      inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));   

                //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse  
                close( sd );   
                client_socket[i] = 0;   
            }   

            //Echo back the message that came in  
            else 
            {   
                //set the string terminating NULL byte on the end  
                //of the data read  
                buffer[valread] = '\0';   
                send(sd , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );                     
            }   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the initialization of `timeout`, you only initialize the `tv_usec` field, not the `tv_sec` field which will have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random/garbage) value.

Comment: And many single-threaded servers that needs to handle other events works very similar to that. There used to be an old genre of games called [MUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD), whose servers were mostly single-threaded and had many events happening seemingly asynchronously, and they did it using timeouts to `select` just like you do. Today one would probably use threads for parallelism and asynchronous operations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you mean using one thread for each client?

Comment: That's one solution, or one thread for all communication (using `select` with a null timeout) and another for other events.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. I put all the `main()` function from the example I found on geeksforgeeks into a thread. The code I posted above are the changes I made in that example. How could I break the select from another thread? I just want to be able to send data to a client whenever I have to send some. But I can't cause the `select` blocks forever (with `NULL` timeout is set) if no data received from a socket

Comment: I just tried to put the `send` function in the thread that creates the data to be sent and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with this code is that it sends data to the connected clients only when data received.

That is because the original code implements a request/response server - in this case, it is specifically an echo server.

> I want to send data to the connected clients asynchonously.

You may want to first enumerate the condition(s)/trigger(s) under which the server starts sending data asynchronously. One example, that I'm making up impromptu, is a multi-echo server. Once such a server receives a string from the client, it echoes it 3 times, each echo separated by (say) 1 second.

In such a case, the select time-out can be used to break the wait and the "if buffer[0] > 0" check can be modified to send any pending echoes.

> The question is: Is there any better way to do what I want? Can I force select() to timeout with other way?

The [man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) indicates that there is a third way to break out of select, by arranging for a signal to be delivered. But, I think, that should be used for handling signals delivered to the server program and only the select timeout for dealing with asynchronous IO. More accurately, I have seen production grade servers that use the epoll/kqueue (better alternatives to select) timeout in their async loop. So, your approach seems quite reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common for single-threaded servers that have a big loop around a call to `select` or `poll` to have a list of "timers" -- things that have to be done at a particular time. When there's nothing the code needs to do, you check how long it is until the list of timers indicates that something needs to be done and you call `select` or `poll` specifying that length of time as the timeout.

So your loop tends to look like this:

1. Check the list of timers and calculate how long until we need to do something.
2. Call `select` or `poll` specifying that as the timeout.
3. If we discovered any sockets are ready for operations, do those operations.
4. If it's time to execute any timers, execute them.
5. Go to step 1.

If you need to do something periodically, set an initial timer to do that thing the first time. Then have the timer's execution code set a new timer to do the thing again.

Comment: How about putting the `send` function in another thread? I tried it and seems to work fine! One thread listens from the connected clients and the `select` blocks forever and the other thread just executes `send` when data need to be sent.

Comment: @MrBit You can certainly do that. Using more than one thread makes the architecture simpler. The downside is that you do have to understand how to synchronize threads and avoid race conditions. But once you've learned how to do that, multi-threading is definitely the way to go.